# How can I select CALayer in swift by index?

Tags: swift, calayer

I added some `CALayers` in view on swift. If i did something wrong, please tell me how can i make it better.

```
for index in 1...5 {
    nowCard = CALayer()
    nowCard.backgroundColor = colorMain.CGColor
    nowCard.frame = CGRectMake(fromX, fromY, cardsWidth, cardsHeight)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(nowCard, atIndex: UInt32(index))
}
```

In next step i must select one of them. In obj-c i could do this with `objectAtIndex`, but now i can't. How can i select one layer by index?

Answer (score 1):

Small example for you with minor fixes:

```
    let nowCard = CALayer()
    let myView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200))

    for index in 1...5 {
        nowCard.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        nowCard.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200)
        myView.layer.insertSublayer(nowCard, atIndex: 1)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did it.

```
var layerNow: CALayer
layerNow = self.layer.sublayers[atIndex] as CALayer
```